# Set margin-left buffer on both sides of jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery slider and my slider handle is pretty big. In order for it to be the way I want it has to have `margin-left: -2px` when it's at 0 (all the way to the left) and have `margin-left: -32px` when it's at 100 (all the way to the right).

I want to ease into the correct margin rather than setting it upruptly. It can be done using the slide event but I'm having a little trouble with the calculation:

```
$(...).slider({
     slide: function(event, ui){
         var newMarginLeft = ...calculation... (ui.value is 0-100)
         $(this).children(".ui-handle").css("marginLeft", newMarginLeft);
     }
});
```

Comment: explain more in detail

Comment: So, you need a calculation that is specific and increments linearly a total of 30 increments, when `ui.value = 0`, it should return `2`, and than when `ui.value = 100` it should return `32` however, it needs to append a negative value onto it when using in marginLeft.  Should be straight forward for any mathematician to come up with a formula for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function, which will generate numbers from 2 to 32 evenly:

```
function generateNum(num)
{
    return 2 + Math.floor(num * .30);
}
```

Than you will just add a negative onto it.  Use like this:

```
$(...).slider({
     slide: function(event, ui){
         var newMarginLeft = "-" + generateNum(ui.value);
         $(this).children(".ui-handle").css("marginLeft", newMarginLeft + "px");
     }
})
```

jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/RWuR4/1/

You can also try using Math.round to round up:  Here is a fiddle that uses Math.round, which makes 99 also return 32 (so it might be a bit more of what you want instead of Math.floor):

http://jsfiddle.net/RWuR4/2/